# Emails are saved in database with 0 as value

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio

I am doing a Register login activities for my app and when I register all the info are going to my database except for the Email.  I got a "0" as value in the database even if I entered a normal email address.

I checked everything in my code and my php files, but cannot find the problem.

```
public class createAccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText etUsername,etEmail, etAge, etPassword;
Button register;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.createaccount);


    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.create_username);
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.create_email);
    etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.create_age);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.create_password);
    etConfirmPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confirm_password);




}

@Override
public void onClick (View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.register:


            String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
            int age = Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());
            String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            User user = new User(username, email, age, password);
            registerUser(user);

            break;
    }

}

private void registerUser(User user) {
    ServerRequests serverRequest = new ServerRequests(this);
    serverRequest.storeUserDataInBackground(user, new GetUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(User returnedUser) {
            Intent loginIntent = new Intent(createAccountActivity.this, Login.class);
            startActivity(loginIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

In my UserLocalStore.java I got

```
public void storeUserData(User user) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor userLocalDatabaseEditor = userLocalDatabase.edit();
    userLocalDatabaseEditor.putString("username", user.username);
    userLocalDatabaseEditor.putString("email", user.email);
    userLocalDatabaseEditor.putString("password", user.password);
    userLocalDatabaseEditor.putInt("age", user.age);
    userLocalDatabaseEditor.commit();
}
```

My class User

```
public class User {

String username, email, password;
int age;

public User(String username,String email , int age, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.age = age;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}

public User(String username, String password) {
    this(username,"", -1, password);
}
}
```

And my ServerRequests.class

```
if (jObject.length() != 0){
                Log.v("happened", "2");
                String username = jObject.getString("username");
                int age = jObject.getInt("age");
                String email = jObject.getString("email");

                returnedUser = new User(username,  user.username, age, user.password);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return returnedUser;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer was simple, In my register.php it was writen "siss" and not "ssis" so it was seen as an int.

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $username, $email, $age,  $password);
```

correct one :

`mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssis", $username, $email, $age,  $password);`

Sorry I should have provide it (php file), no wonder I didn't get a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that returnedUser in ServerRequests.class puts user.username where the email should be, since you have declared it as

```
public User(String username,String email , int age, String password)
```

and it says

```
returnedUser = new User(username,  user.username, age, user.password);
```

in the other file.

Comment: changed it with `returnedUser = new User(user.username, email, age, user.password);` but still no good

Comment: What datatype have you registered for the email in the database? If it is Int (by misstake) that might explain it too

Comment: varchar(50) latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: And this line fires?
    Log.v("happened", "2");

Comment: Nothing but even if I delete it it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ok, I´m not really a Java programmer and I´m going to bed in a while but here´s my last attempt (for tonight atleast). The line "etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.create_email);", is create_email actually spelled right in the view?

Comment: Yes alreadly checked, but thanks anyway I appreciate very much that you are trying to help!